# What will be the probability in gunshot?

Tags: probability

A man shot a target for '$n$' times.

'$X$' times he hit the target. '$Y$' times he missed the target.
($X+Y=n$). 
What is the probability that he will hit(be succesful) in his $(n+1)th$ shot ?

Comment: Where are you having trouble with this question? What are your thoughts? What sort of help are you looking for?

Comment: I feel the probability will be X/n . But I am not sure/confused.

Comment: That is a good intuition. With the very small amount of information you have, that is a reasonable (albeit simplistic) way to view the probability. The assumption is that over a long period of time, the shooter will approach an average probability of hitting the target at which point his shooting percentage will no longer improve. So, for large enough values of $n$, this will be fairly accurate. A good number to use as "large enough" is 30. With 30 or more data points, you can be fairly confident in your average.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer may heavily depends on how the shots are (cor)related. By now it's impossible to say!
I give you 2 examples:

1. The tries are independent. Immagine the man can not learn form the errors, and each time he tries he has a probability of $ \frac{1}{2}$. Than he will have again a probability of $ \frac{1}{2}$ in the $ n+1$ try.
2. He can actually learn from the past: then, the answer is a function of the successes, $f(X)$, and the answer depends on how fast can he learns, i.e. the function $f(\cdot)$